# How to dig a hole in a cube object?

Tags: three.js

I use cubes to simulate walls of a room, and I wonder whether there is some methods to simulate door or window in a certain wall. All in all, can I dig a cube hole in a cube object using ThreeJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *Constructive Solid Geometry*. There are several libraries which permits to add some boolean operations on solids:

- [first cgs.js tutorial](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/)
- [second cgs.js tutorial](http://www.chandlerprall.com/2011/12/constructive-solid-geometry-with-three-js/)
- [third cgs.js tutorial](http://evanw.github.io/csg.js/)

To create your room, you would first create the external cube , then substract to it a mesh representing the window / door, and substract to the result the internal cube.

But seriously, regarding the tasks you are trying to achieve, you should learn to create your model with [blender](http://www.blender.org/) and import it to your scene with one of these loaders:

- [JSONLoader](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader)
- [ColladaLoader](http://jiteshmulchandani.com/?p=122) (optimised for maya or 3ds)
- [CTMLoader](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_ctm.html) (optimised for compression).

Hope this helps